# Reduction for distinguishing to elements

Tags: provable-security

Given a composite number $n=pq$ of primes $p$ and $q$, a secret random element $r$, and two public random elements $x_1$ and $x_2$. An adversary is given two elements, $y_1= x_1^r \mod n$ and $y_2=x_2^r \mod n$, and its goal is to correctly match $x_1$ with $y_1$ and $x_2$ with $y_2$, with probability $\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon(n)$ where $\epsilon$ is a non neglible function. Is there a security reduction that can be used to prove this?

Comment: Is the adversary also given $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a reduction to show that this is hard for an adversary? If so, the answer is no because distinguishing is easy in roughly 1/4 of the cases.

Comment: Yes, the adversary is also given $x_1$  and $x_2$.

Comment: @DanielS can you please elaborate in which cases it is easy to distinguish between $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Comment: HINT: Jacobi symbols

Comment: @DanielS, right. It seems to be easy just by checking the Jacobi symbol of the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s. However, it is not clear in the case where you make sure that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are selected randomly from a quadratic residue group, e.g., by finding some random element that is QR (I guess by taking random $t$ and computing $g=t^2 \mod n$ as a generator) and then compute $x_1 = g^{r_1}$ and $x_2 = g^{r_2}$.